# Screen Time doesn't work for Safari on Big Sur

Tags: safari, screen-time

I want to set a limit for a website on macOS Big Sur with Safari.

No matter what I do, the screen limit doesn't work.

I set time limit for twitter like this, yet I keep being on twitter longer than 5 minutes and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? How to debug this?

[image]

Comment: I will gladly tell more information... if I know what debug info to post. (I am a developer, but not for macOS apps/internals)

Comment: It started working magically. ....ok.