# How can I block the Twitter website on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-configurator, twitter, screen-time

**Question:** How can I block the Twitter website on iPhone with Apple Configurator? I want to block Twitter in order to reduce my screen time. Configurator is an app for installing configuration profiles. Among other things, a profile can filter content.

**Specific Websites Only:** I tried installing a profile with a Content Filter payload for Specific Websites Only. I allowed only one website: http://example.com. Please see the following screenshot of the Specific Websites Only profile. This blocked other websites, but it did not block the Twitter website.

[image: Specific Websites Only]

**Limit Adult Content:** I also tried installing a profile with a Content Filter payload to Limit Adult Content. I did not give any Allowed URLs, and I gave the following four Unallowed URLs: http://twitter.com, https://twitter.com, http://mobile.twitter.com, https://mobile.twitter.com. Please see the following screenshot of the Limit Adult Content profile. This also did not block the Twitter website.

[image: Limit Adult Content]

**Screen Time:** I would rather not use Screen Time because it only supports a four-digit PIN –– not an arbitrary-length password. For more information, please see the question ["Screen Time Passcode: Use Password rather than 4-digit PIN?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372221/screen-time-passcode-use-password-rather-than-4-digit-pin) on Ask Different.

I tried Screen Time nevertheless. In the Never Allow section of Web Content settings, I added the the following two URLs: mobile.twitter.com and twitter.com. Please see the following screenshot of Web Content settings. This also did not block the Twitter website.

[image: Web Content Settings]

**Related:** Karel Bik asked the question ["Screen Time doesn't work for Safari on Big Sur"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412572/screen-time-doesnt-work-for-safari-on-big-sur) on Ask Different. This question refers to Screen Time for Mac, and my question refers to Screen Time for iPhone.

[Scott Hanselman](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/1621068997377810432) tweeted, "Screen Time on iOS is a joke. It’s been a hot mess since iOS 14. It turns off randomly. Limits aren’t hard limits, Downtime turns off every few days. Super frustrating for parents."

**Tags:** The iPhone tag on Super User says, "iPhone-related questions must involve connecting the device to a computer." The iOS tag also says, "Questions about iOS devices are off-topic except insofar as they interact directly with computers." This question involves connecting the iPhone to Mac because Configurator only runs on Mac –– not on iPhone. Therefore this question is in scope for both of these tags.

Comment: hi, any update on this?

Comment: @Thomas Unfortunately no, I still do not know how to block the Twitter website on iPhone. As a workaround, you could try blocking the Safari app entirely.